# unefficient "on-purpose" hash

Tags: algorithm, hash

My question may sound a bit strange:
I know that hash functions used for encryption must have the characteristic to greatly change the outputs even for small changes of one bit due to some sort of avalanche effect.

Does an **unefficent** hash exist with the characteristic that for *similar* strings it produces similar outputs?

If the answer is yes, can you tell me if there is a way to manipulate this aspect (the definition of "*similar*") with underlying, pre-known relations between the characters of a text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of hashing functions are called [locality sensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing).

Comment: This "answer" should be a comment. Unless you intend to flesh it out a little bit with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it exists. As you expect the definition of *similar* must be given. But it depends on your application - I can just give an example.

Suppose your strings are domains and you want to hash all subdomains into one bucket. Then you can reverse strings like:

```
finance.yahoo.com => com.yahoo.finance
sport.yahoo.com => com.yahoo.sport
user.mail.yahoo.com => com.yahoo.mail.user
```

and hash only the first two parts: `com.yahoo`, dropping the rest. Your hash function can look like this (in python):

```
def hash(url):
    return any_other_hash_function(".".join(url.split(".")[::-1][:2]))
```

Your question is not strange at all. You can find similar approach in Google's map-reduce or BigTable (and in many many other systems) for keeping similar things altogether, so that one can speed up computations.

The example I gave is for strings, but you can use similar approach for other objects. Here the idea is just to separate items into groups and hash the group id (high-level domain name).